# Run PHP script in same directory as wordpress, but without it

Tags: php, database, cron

Let's say I've got a PHP script called import.php (code at the bottom) which is stored in the same directory (root) as my wordpress website. My issue is when I would like to run that script by typing: www.mydomain.com/import.php of course it launches wordpress with 404 ERROR.

How can I run this script somehow outside wordpress environment / exclude it from wordpress?

My script is dedicated to database update (via real cron), that's why i dont want to use wordpress for that.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_username = '';
$mysql_password = '';
$mysql_database = '';

$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$mysql_database.';host='.$mysql_host,$mysql_username,$mysql_password);

// works not with the following set to 0. You can comment this line as 1 is default
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);

function truncate_db()
{
    global $db;

    $sql_query_1 = "
    TRUNCATE TABLE `WIZYTY`; 
    TRUNCATE TABLE `ANIMALS`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `DOCTORS`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `CUSTOMER`
    "; 

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql_query_1);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "Truncate action - OK";
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
}

function import_db()
{
    global $db;

    try
       {
         $sql_query_2 = implode(array_map(function ($v) {
            return file_get_contents($v);
            }, glob(__DIR__ . "/*.sql")));

         $qr = $db->exec($sql_query_2); 
         echo "Import action - OK";
       }
       catch (PDOException $e) 
       {
         echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

truncate_db();
echo '<br />';
import_db();

$db = null;
?>
```

Comment: You need to add an exception in the set of rewriting rules wordpress generated. Those are stored by wordpress in a `.htaccess` style file. The exception for that script in there will prevent wordpress to "take over" handling of that request.

Comment: Why? Actually if is your root folder (where wp-config.php is placed usually) should work as web server will handle it before WordPress. Same as http://yourdomain.com/license.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add something like this on 
.htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "^import\.php$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Anyway, you shouldn't have it on the root folder, check wordpress for better solutions

Wordpress Event Scheduler
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

And here you have a great example
https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/